# How to execute a function within the scope of a predicate

Tags: kotlin

How could I execute an isCaractererValido() function within the scope of a predicate(takeWhile)?

```
fun isValidIdentifier(s: String): Boolean {
    if (s.takeWhile { !isCaractererValido(it) }.isNullOrEmpty()) return true;
    fun isCaractererValido(ch: Char) = 
            ch == '_' || ch.isLetterOrDigit()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local functions are required to be declared before they get called:

```kotlin
fun isValidIdentifier(s: String): Boolean {
    fun isCaractererValido(ch: Char) = ch == '_' || ch.isLetterOrDigit()

    if (s.takeWhile { !isCaractererValido(it) }.isNullOrEmpty()) return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll kick yourself: just **move the local function *above* where it's called**, e.g.:

```
fun isValidIdentifier(s: String): Boolean {
    fun isCaractererValido(ch: Char)
            = ch == '_' || ch.isLetterOrDigit()

    if (s.takeWhile{ !isCaractererValido(it) }.isNullOrEmpty())
        return true
}
```

Functions are like variables in that respect.  Although you can define properties within a class in any order (subject to a few restrictions), within a function you can only use a local variable after it's defined; and it's the same with functions too: local functions can only be used after they've been defined.

In this particular case, I'm not convinced that a local function is really justified.  If there's a business reason for which characters are allowed in identifiers, then it probably justifies a public function (perhaps at the top level, or in a companion object).  Or if not, then it would be simpler without the function, simply using the condition directly.  — But of course that's a matter of opinion and style, not correctness.

Also, I have concerns about the correctness and performance of your code.

First, it doesn't compile, because it's not returning anything if the `if` test fails.  You should either add a `return false` below it, or simply return the value of the test, without an `if`.

What it *seems* to be trying to do is check whether the identifiers *starts* with one or more valid characters; it will return `true` if the first character is valid, even if any later one isn't.  (It also returns `true` if the string is empty, which doesn't seem like a good idea.)  Is that what you intended?

Because if so, there's no need to collect *all* the invalid character(s) at the start; you can just check the first one, e.g.:

```
fun isValidIdentifier(s: String)
    = s.isNotEmpty() && (s[0] == '_' || s[0].isLetterOrDigit())
```

Shorter, simpler, and faster (as it only checks one character, and doesn't create any new objects).  It also has an explicit check rejecting an empty string.

Even if that's *not* what you want, then you still probably don't need to create a new list.  If you want to check that *every* character is valid, then you could use [all()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/all.html):

```
fun isValidIdentifier(s: String)
    = s.isNotEmpty() && s.all{ it == '_' || it.isLetterOrDigit() }
```

Finally, a function like this is often more elegant if written as an extension function on String:

```
fun String.isValidIdentifier()
    = isNotEmpty() && all{ it == '_' || it.isLetterOrDigit() }
```

That way, you can call it with e.g. `if (myString.isValidIdentifier()) …`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `isCaracterValido` before you use it.

```
fun isValidIdentifier(s: String): Boolean {
  fun isCaractererValido(ch: Char) =
    ch == '_' || ch.isLetterOrDigit()
  return isNotEmpty() && s.all { isCaractererValido(it) }
}
```

I also took the liberty of simplifying your code. All you want is that all characters return `true` for `isCaractererValido` in order for `isValidIdentifier` to return `true`.

---

If your local function is so simply I would actually inline it.

```
fun isValidIdentifier(s: String): Boolean = isNotEmpty() && s.all { it == '_' || it.isLetterOrDigit() }
```